# How to reflect type of currency in URL links?

Tags: magento-1.7, currency

As many of you know when switching currency in MAGENTO store, it does not reflect in URL's.

Let say your BASE store currency is in CANADIAN DOLLARS, when sending links by Email to customers in EUROPE, the page they will open will show CAD (Canadian dollar) prices rather than EURO. They have to manually switch currency in the top right corner of the website.

**What to add at the end of all links so the prices are shown in EURO ?**
I need  an ending like: ?_currency=EURO

www.exmaple.com/sport-equipment/soccerball/**?_currency=EURO**

Comment: Is this code for magento v1.7 only? what about v1.9?

Comment: I have not idea, I still haven't got it working.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way of doing that, but it's a bit ugly.
The url must look like this:

```
{ROOT}/directory/currency/switch/currency/{CURRENCY_CODE}/uenc/{ENCODED REDIRECT URL}/
```

So if your url is `http://www.exmaple.com/sport-equipment/soccerball/`, the url you send in the e-mail for EUR must look like this:

`http://www.exmaple.com/currency/switch/currency/EUR/uenc/aHR0cDovL3d3dy5leG1hcGxlLmNvbS9zcG9ydC1lcXVpcG1lbnQvc29jY2VyYmFsbC8,`

You can build this url starting from your url like this.

```
$currency = 'EUR';
$redirect = 'http://www.exmaple.com/sport-equipment/soccerball/';
$mageBaseUrl = `http://www.exmaple.com/`
$emailUrl = $mageBaseUrl.'directory/currency/switch/currency/'.$currency.'/uenc/'.strtr(base64_encode($redirect), '+/=', '-_,');
```

It's easier if you build the url in a magento environment:

```
$currency = 'EUR';
$redirect = 'http://www.exmaple.com/sport-equipment/soccerball/';
$emailUrl = Mage::getUrl('directory/currency/switch', array(
    'currency' => $currency,
    Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED => Mage::helper('core')->urlEncode($redirect)
));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I need an extension that I can attach to ALL links and not just one link
http://www.exmaple.com/sport-equipment/soccerball. I wonder why magento didint think about this, as really its an essential function, and I see many stores have some sort of link code in the url when you manually switch currency.

Comment: Marius, one questions, how will google crawlers reach to seeing two links http://www.exmaple.com/sport-equipment/soccerball/ and http://www.exmaple.com/sport-equipment/soccerball/aHR0cDovL3d3dy5leG1hcGxlLmNvbS9zcG9ydC1lcXVpcG1lbnQvc29jY2VyYmFsbC8. Will they ban both of them from search engines ? or there something could be  done in ROBOTS.TXT file so google picks up files with BASE currency only ?

Comment: I don't know how google crawlers work.